# model not valid when loading custom trained model to ml5 imageClassifier

Tags: angular, ml5.js

I have trained my own model on [Teachable Machine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/image) and i downloaded it and then i tested it, it worked fine using pure javascript code, but when i tried to implement it on my angular project using the ml5 package, i had some issues when i tried to pass to him the trained model that i have, it always keeps telling me that my model is not valid even though i followed the whole documentation on [ML5 documentation](https://ml5js.org/reference/api-ImageClassifier/) where they said that i could pass an url to my trained model as a parameter but still the same issues, i didn't know where the problem is cooming from.

my component functions for loading model :

```
async loadModel() {
    this.model = await ml5.imageClassifier('https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/models/6QKQUqglC/model.json', this.modelLoadedf);
    console.log(this.model);
    this.modelLoaded = true;
    await this.loadTrainableModel();
}

 async loadTrainableModel() {
    // Initialize the Image Classifier method with MobileNet
    this.customModel.modelLoaded = false;
    const features = await ml5.featureExtractor('https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/models/6QKQUqglC/model.json');
    console.log('feature extractor loaded ....');

    this.customModel.model = await features.classification();
    console.log('custom classifier loaded....');
    this.customModel.modelLoaded = true;
}
```

the two " imageClassifier " and "featureExtractor" always returning error because of the model i passed to them.

is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The same logic you mentioned is implemented here in React. This might help: https://dementorwriter.medium.com/picture-classification-with-react-ml5-c45672aeb961

```
      const setup = (p5: p5Types, canvasParentRef: Element) => {
        capture.current = p5.createCapture(p5.VIDEO).parent(canvasParentRef);
        const featureExtractor = ml5.featureExtractor("MobileNet", {epochs: props.numberOfEpochs}, modelReady);
        classifier.current = featureExtractor.classification(
          capture.current,
          videoReady
        );
      };
```